# Find cell(s) with certain text and add hyperlinks in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

**tldr**: Find cell(s) with part number xxxxx and add hyperlink to drawing on server.

We have a spreadsheet containing part numbers across multiple columns & rows. Our requirement is to add a hyperlink to parts' drawing, stored on our server. We have tried highlighting them as a group, but get the error

> this can't be done on multiple range selection

We also want to keep the comment information intact, just to complicate it further.

Is there code we can use to search for `part number xxxxx` & add a hyperlink, then find the next cell and repeat the process?

We have found a "find all" code which highlights the cells, just need some help with the hyperlink issue.

```
Sub FindAll()

    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

    'What value do you want to find (must be in string form)?
    fnd = "70005"

    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

    'Test to see if anything was found
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
    Else
        GoTo NothingFound
    End If

    Set rng = FoundCell

    'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        'Find next cell with fnd value
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

        'Add found cell to rng range variable
        Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

        'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

    Loop

    'Select Cells Containing Find Value
    rng.Select

    Exit Sub

    'Error Handler
    NothingFound:
    MsgBox "No values were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: There are hundreds of part numbers, part number could be across a 12 columns and 100s of rows,and every part number has a unique drawing if there is a solution we may have to make a code for every part number and hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method can be simplified a bit. My suggestion is to create a function that will add your hyperlinks to any given area.

My test data is

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim linkCount As Long
    linkCount = AddHyperLinkTo(FindArea:=Sheet1.UsedRange, _
                               FindThis:="red", _
                               Link:="https://google.com")
    Debug.Print "found: " & linkCount
End Sub

Function AddHyperLinkTo(ByRef FindArea As Range, _
                        ByVal FindThis As Variant, _
                        ByVal Link As String) As Long

    Dim numberFound As Long
    Dim parentWS As Worksheet
    Set parentWS = FindArea.Parent

    Dim firstFind As Range
    Dim findResult As Range
    Set findResult = FindArea.Find(What:=FindThis, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set firstFind = findResult
    Do Until findResult Is Nothing
        parentWS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=findResult, Address:=Link
        numberFound = numberFound + 1
        Set findResult = FindArea.Find(What:=FindThis, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=findResult)
        If findResult.Address = firstFind.Address Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    AddHyperLinkTo = numberFound
End Function
```

Comment: This is spot on, we will have to change it for every part no. & hyperlink, this is going to save us hours of work, cant thank you enough.